# Why won't Bacula work without the label command?

Tags: backup, bacula

I followed the instructions [here](https://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-bacula-in-ubuntu-15-04/) for setting up Bacula, but when I test it by going into bconsole and running a backup, it doesn't work.

There is one step missing from those instructions. You have to use the label command in bconsole, and then you supply any name. After that if you try to run a backup it works.

Why do you have to use the label command, and how come you don't have to put the name of the label in any configuration files?

Comment: Which instructions did you follow?  What error are/were you getting?

Comment: https://www.unixmen.com/install-and-configure-bacula-in-ubuntu-15-04/